# How can I prove that $f(| a|) = -|a|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Set the function $f(x) = |x| - 2x,~x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f(|a|) = -|a|$.
How can I do this? I have no idea.

Comment: Plug in $|a|$ for $x$ and simplify what do you get?

Comment: What do I do with a module within a module?

Comment: Using absolute value on a number twice equals using it only once, since after using it once, you will get a positive number, using at again will make nothing.

Comment: In other words, $||a||=|a|$. Try to show that this is true when $a$ is $-1$, $0$, or $1$. Then try to show that it's true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to use the definition: $f(|a|)=||a||-2|a|= |a|-2|a|=-|a|$.

$||a||=|a|$ can be done, since using absolute value on a number twice equals using it only once, since after using it once, you will get a positive number, using at again will make nothing.

Comment: Sorry, this is quite shameful. But how do you solve this - 2|a|?

Comment: I used $x= |a|$, and I typed that in your definition you gave me, it gives $-2x$ in the end, so this must give $-2|a|$ in the end. :)

Comment: @tumbler Once you get the equation to $|a| - 2|a|$, do you know how to find $x - 2x$?  It is just $-x$, right?  Well, $|a| - 2 |a| = - |a|$ for the same reason.  We have one of $|a|$ and we are taking away two of $|a|$, so that means we are left with $-|a|$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply plug in $x=|a|$:

$$f(|a|) = ||a||-2|a| = |a|-2|a| = -|a|. $$

Since $|a|\geq 0$, we have that $||a|| = |a|.$ This is due to the fact that the absolute value function doesn't change anything when in the input is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

Recall what the absolute value function does:

$f(x) = |x|$ means $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \geq 0 \\ -x & x < 0 \end{cases}$, right?  Basically, if the input is positive, the absolute value is just the input.  If the input is negative, the absolute value is the positive version of the input.

Then what does $||x||$ mean?  Well, by definition, this is $= |x|$ if $|x| \geq 0$ or $-|x|$ if $|x| < 0$.  But is $|x|$ ever $< 0$?  Of course not.  So $||x|| = |x|$ for every $x$.

In words, since $|x|$ is positive, then taking its absolute value just gives you it back since that's what the absolute value function does to positive inputs.  So $||x|| = |x|$.  Once you understand this point, the other answers should make sense to you.